# Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with this script.  I debugged in console and have a syntax error.  Can someone put eyes on this and tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
jQuery('.priceGreyText').each(function () {
                if (jQuery(this).text() == 'Starting at') {
                    jQuery(this).text('Starts ');
                } else if (jQuery(this).text() == 'To') {
                    jQuery(this).closest('.kuSalePrice').remove();
                }
            });
```

Comment: i am not getting an error.  are you sure jquery is loaded on to the page?

Comment: yes, I tried using alert and it worked.

Comment: i dont believe that's a good test for jquery

Comment: ```window.onload = function() {
   if (window.jQuery) {  
       // jQuery is loaded  
       alert("Yeah!");
   } else {
    location.reload();
   }
}```

Comment: well probably need more info.  i can open a dev console with f12 on this page and copy your code into the console and run it and it works with no errors.  i've also tried to make it go into each of the logic sections in the if statement and got it ot run with no errors, so i'm at a lost what to tell you as i can get it to work

Comment: What kind of info will help?  I already have implemented this on my site for another page.  using it this way...  ```if(window.location.pathname.indexOf("/search/")!=-1){

  function CheckStartingtext(){
   

   jQuery(".priceGreyText").each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).text()=="Starting at"){
     jQuery(this).text("Starts ");

    }else if(jQuery(this).text()=="To"){
     jQuery(this).closest(".kuSalePrice").remove();
    }

    

   });
```